# Querying JSON array in Nuxt 3 with Nuxt Content

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt-content

How do I query a JSON array for a single element in Nuxt 3 and Nuxt Content?

```
├── @nuxt/content@2.3.0
└── nuxt@3.0.0
```

`content/people.json`

```
[
  {
    "name": "Name1",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Name2",
    "id": 2
  }
]
```

Querying all of the people data results in this:

```
[
  {
    "_path": "/people",
    "_dir": "",
    "_draft": false,
    "_partial": false,
    "_locale": "en",
    "body": [
      {
        "name": "Name1",
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "Name2",
        "id": 2
      }
    ],
    "_id": "content:people.json",
    "_type": "json",
    "title": "People",
    "_source": "content",
    "_file": "people.json",
    "_extension": "json"
  }
]
```

`pages/people/[id].vue`

```
<template>
  <pre>{{ data }}</pre>
</template>

<script setup>
const route = useRoute();
const id = route.params.id;

const data = await queryContent("people")
  .where({ id }) // **What should this be? I can't seem to get any variants to work**
  .findOne();
</script>
```

I can query the full array of people okay on the index page. However, I would like to now get the single "person" out of the JSON array on the `[id].vue` page, but I'm not sure how to query this document with a `where` clause in Nuxt Content.

Comment: Actually, perhaps this doesn't work at all at the moment: https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/1814

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this question comes from a misunderstanding of the functionality of `where()` clause. This clause according to [nuxt-content docs](https://content.nuxtjs.org/api/composables/query-content#wherequery) is used to **Filter results by query**. That means the results come from **content** directory of the nuxt app, Not the contents **inside** each file. It filters the files and folders, not the contents of them. For example when we say `const { data } = await useAsyncData('list', () => queryContent('/list').where({ title: 'list1 page' }).findOne());`, we want to filter the **files** inside the `content/list` directory and find the file that has `title: 'list1 page'`. We could not filter or change the contents inside the for example **list1.md** or **list1.json** or... files with `where()` clause.

For the case of this question, I think that we have two options:

- The first one is that we filter the results in the `people/[id].vue` file after we get them from `queryContent` (without using `where()`) with the help of pure JavaScript (for example with [filter() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)) to get the person information according to id data.
- The second option that I think is better, because allows us to benefit from nuxt-content features and functionalities is to **change** the data structure. To do that we must create a folder inside our `content` directory called `people`. Then inside that we create files like `1.person1.json`, `2.person2.json` and so on. Inside each file we have json data of that specific person like the code below:

  {
  "name": "Name1",
  "id": 1
  }

  Then with a code like this one in `pages/people/[id].vue` file you can access the data of each person automatically according to the **id** of that person:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ $route.params.id }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const route = useRoute();
console.log(route.params.id);
const { data } = await useAsyncData('people', () => queryContent('people', "person"+ route.params.id).findOne());
console.log(data.value.name);
</script>
```

As you can see, in the second option we don't need to use `where()` clause at all, because the changing data structures makes the filtering process better and easier.